# dash separated params in routing angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to separate my params in URL by dash like below:

```
localhost/add/5-ninja
```

in here the id is 5 and the name is ninja. When i changed the config to this:
`path: '/:id-:name'`
It doesn't work properly.
How can I create dash separated params in URL

Comment: This is not supported by Angular.  You will have to pass the entire parameter and then fetch the `id` part in your controller/component.

Comment: Similar [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17742)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible the way you like but here's my suggestion to achieve that result:

- in your routes config you declare the path: for ex. `/:dashed`
- in your component:

  ```
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  class MyComponent {
  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
      const [id, name] = _route.snapshot.params.dashed.split('-');
      // you've got two variables 'id' and 'name' thanks to the array destructing
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> You could use a custom [UrlSerializer](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer) to parse the URL as you see fit.

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17742#issuecomment-350126533)