# Angular routing: adding a prefix to child :ID path

Tags: angular, path, router

I have the following routes in my routing file:

```
{
    path: 'new', component: CreateTeamComponent
},
{
    path: ':ID-TEAM', children: [
        {
            path: 'edit', component: EditTeamComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit-player/:ID-PLAYER', component: EditPlayerComponent
        },
        {
            path: '', component: TeamDetailsComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to replace `'edit-player/:ID-PLAYER'` with `'edit-player-:ID-PLAYER'` to have url like this: `/teams/1111/edit-player-222222`.

The first approach works, but it could be a bit confusing for the users since there is nothing to see at `'edit-player'` path. The second one leads me to page not found fallback.

How to solve?

Comment: If you have something that works, why change it to something that won't? What is the reason for going this direction?

Comment: You could simply use a parameter for the whole "edit-player-<id>" string and parse it. If it starts with "edit-player-" use the remaining chars as the id, otherwise redirect to the not found page for example.

Comment: @MatthiasThalmann your solution seems to be similar to mine. Boths solutions create this url `/teams/111/edit-player-222` where `222` changes according to the player I select, but it doesn't redirect to the right component and always opens page-not-found path :(

Comment: @R.Richards I answered you editing my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dash separated params in routing angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727014/dash-separated-params-in-routing-angular-5)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Angular's UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher) to apply regex for edit-player path.

It would be something like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        matcher: url => {
            console.log(url);
            if (url[url.length - 1].path.match(/^edit-player-[\d]+$/gm)) {
                return {
                    consumed: url,
                    posParams: {
                        playerId: new UrlSegment(
                            url[url.length - 1].path.split('-').slice(-1)[0],
                            {}
                        )
                    }
                };
            }

            return null;
        },
        component: EditPlayerComponent
    }
])
```

[Example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ioaukx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Will the `UrlMatcher` be given priority and consume the route event, if the regex accidentally or intentionally partially matches another route?

Comment: That will depend on which route do you provide first in the routes array. Here is stackblitz link which demonstrated that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ioaukx-8zcgxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: In my case `url` is an empty array so your solution doesn't work. Anyway I think I will go for redirect solution since using of hyphen seems not to be supported by Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17742

Answer (score 2):

If the first approach works, and your concern is that the route `edit-player` could be confusing; then you may set up a redirect on that path.

```
{
    path: 'new', component: CreateTeamComponent
},
{
    path: ':ID-TEAM', children: [
        {
            path: 'edit', component: EditTeamComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit-player/:ID-PLAYER', component: EditPlayerComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit-player', redirectTo: ':ID-TEAM/edit', pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: '', component: TeamDetailsComponent
        }
    ]
}
```